# SpringBoot Thymeleaf: "Required parameter 'department' is not present."

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm building a spring application using PostgreSQL as a database and have now tried out thymeleaf, yet I am not capable to even make a @GetMapping. It keeps giving me a Whitelabel Error page with the error stated in the title.

Controller Class:

```java
@Controller
@Slf4j
@SessionAttributes({"department"})
@RequestMapping("/department")
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initDB(){

        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src", "main", "resources", "data.json");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        List<Department> departments = null;

        try {

            departments = mapper.readValue(path.toFile(), new TypeReference<List<Department>>() {});
        

            if(departments != null){

         //Bi-Direktionalität
        
                for(Department department : departments){

                    department.getEmployees().forEach(e -> e.setDepartment(department));

                }

                departmentRepository.saveAll(departments);
        
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    @GetMapping
    public String getDepartmentInfo(Model model, @RequestParam("department") String departmentNumber){

        Department department = departmentRepository.getDepartmentByDeptNo(departmentNumber);

        updateModel(model, department);
        return "departmentView";

    }

    public void updateModel(Model model, Department department){

        model.addAttribute("department", department);
        model.addAttribute("manager", department.getDeptManager());
        model.addAttribute("employees", department.getEmployees());

    }

}
```

My HTML so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Departments</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Department</h1>

<form method="get" th:action="@{/department}">

    <label for="choice"></label>
    <select id="choice" name="department">
        <option th:value="${department.deptNo}" th:text="${department.deptName}"></option>
    </select>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

As I said, I only started with thymeleaf, so mistakes might be obvious to some.

I tried out YouTube Tutorials and searches for other questions on StackOverflow, but none of them could solve my problems.

Comment: Try visiting `http://localhost:port/department?department=xxxx`

Comment: @Gahatma: Please start acknowledging - and, ideally "acccepting" - some of the replies you receive!

Comment: I am unable to do so, as I do not have enough reputation to upvote a comment. It always tells me that I cannot vote, but my feedback is being considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass department value as its mandatory by default

```
http://<host:port>/department?department=<someValue>
```

or you can make department parameter as optional request param as below

```
public String getDepartmentInfo(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "department", required = false) String departmentNumber){...}
```